# Using Entity Framework with Informix

Tags: entity-framework, informix

I've been trying for quite some time to use Entity Framework with our IBM Informix databases.  Hours of searching has pointed me towards installing the IBM .NET Data Server Provider, which I have installed, however when I attempt to add a new Entity Model to my project I only have the Microsoft SQL Server Data Providers listed.  Am I missing a step?  Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert on Windows or .NET; treat any comments I make with due caution.

Installing the .NET Data Server Provider is an important first step.  You now have to make sure that you can use it to connect to the Informix databases you want to manipulate.  There are several things you'll need to check here:

- Is the server (meaning the Informix instance) configured to allow DRDA connections?

  - By default, it probably isn't.
  - If you're the DBSA (database system administrator), you'll need to check that you've enabled 'drsoctcp' connections on the system, and configured a server alias to use that connection.
  - If you're not the DBSA, you'll need to chat with your DBSA to get the relevant information.
- Assuming that you have DRDA connectivity enabled at the server side, you then need to ensure you have an appropriately configured ... DSN?  Your client code needs to be able to connect to the server.

There is no reason I'm aware of why it cannot be done.  However, I don't know exactly how to guide you step-by-step through any of the above.

You might need to seek assistance from IBM Technical Support.

You would help everyone if you clarified which version of Informix (the DBMS) you have, along with the version information for the platform where it is running (whether Windows or Unix, and the o/s version information) - and which version of the Data Server Provider you are using (and which variant of Windows you are using it on).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I know the client can connect to the database without any issue, as I can execute queries programmatically against it, but when attempting to use EntityFramework or LinqToSql Visual Studio doesn't give me the option to use an IBM-compatible Data Adapter.  The only ones listed are the Micrososft SQL Server Adapters.

Comment: You do need the IBM Visual Studio Add-in so you can select the appropriate Connection Providers.